# How to find row with equal value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've got a table `Accounts`

```
AMOUNT| ID_CLIENT | ID_BRANCH
  250      1            1
  250      1            3
  100      1            4
  300      2            1
  300      2            3
  450      3            2
  100      3            2
  225      4            1
  225      4            2
  225      4            4
  225      4            5
```

I need to find clients who have the same amount in every branch (like ID_CLIENT = 2 and ID_CLIENT = 4). I have no idea how can I implement this ( Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical functions to achieve the same:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfde7a/14)

```
with CTE1 as
(
  SELECT A.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CLIENT ORDER BY AMOUNT) DN,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CLIENT) TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TABLE1 A ORDER BY ID_CLIENT
)
SELECT ID_CLIENT FROM 
(
SELECT ID_CLIENT, SUM(DN), TOTAL_COUNT 
  FROM CTE1 
GROUP BY ID_CLIENT, TOTAL_COUNT 
 HAVING SUM(DN) = TOTAL_COUNT
);
```

By using First_value and Last_value:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfde7a/22)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_CLIENT FROM 
(
SELECT A.*, 
FIRST_VALUE(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION  BY ID_CLIENT ORDER BY AMOUNT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) FST_VAL,
LAST_VALUE(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION  BY ID_CLIENT ORDER BY AMOUNT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) LST_VAL
FROM TABLE1 A
) X WHERE FST_VAL = LST_VAL ;
```

Comment: Solution is fine and great but my personal suggestion will be to go for aggression by @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 2):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select client
from (select client, branch, sum(amount) as amount
      from t
      group by client, branch
     ) cb
group by client
having min(amount) = max(amount);
```

I can't tell if you can have multiple rows per client/branch.  If not, you just need:

```
select client
from t
group by client
having min(amount) = max(amount);
```

Comment: @Stitch: just a suggestion, though window function are good and also the answer is correct by the user, in this case using above aggression logic is far better than analytical one.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 . . . I too am baffled why the OP would choose much more complicated approaches to the problem.